# Problem while connecting to DataBase ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, vb.net, oledb

I have a database in the same workspace, I've tried to connect to this DB using this codes :

```
Dim CX As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & "./Learning.mdb")

Dim CX As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & "~/Learning.mdb")

Dim CX As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & "~Learning.mdb")
```

But none of them work.

Comment: Please tell us, in detail, how it "doesn't work".

Comment: File 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Learning.mdb' not found.

Comment: c: \ Program Files \ Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 \ Common7 \ IDE \ ~ \ Learning.mdb 'is not a valid path. Make sure the name of the path is correct and a connection is established with the server on which the file resides.

Comment: ok does the file exist there?

Comment: Sure, it work just if I specify the full path like : "C:\Users\ZiGi\Desktop\IHM\Learning\Learning.mdb" And my website is inside the folder Learning\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
        Dim CX As OleDbConnection = New 
    OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" &
 System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "/Learning.mdb")
```